# VM scale set doesn't allow Diagnostic settings to be sent to Log Analytics

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-rm-template, azure-log-analytics, azure-diagnostics, azure-monitoring

I'm working upon enabling diagnostic settings for VMSS, and VMSS doesn't offer sending diagnostic logs to Log Analytics workspace. Went through some links and found that Windows Diagnostic Extension can achieve this. However; I also read that it supports only azure storage and event hub and doesn't support Log Analytics workspace to collect those logs.

I'm targeting to have ARM template to achieve my objective.
Some links I have gone through are mentioned below:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vm-diagnostics-extension-windows/azuredeploy.json

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostics-extension-overview?toc=/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/toc.json

https://www.catapultsystems.com/blogs/azure-resource-manager-templates-part-one-vm-extensions/

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-GB/azure/azure-monitor/platform/collect-custom-metrics-guestos-resource-manager-vmss

This should tell you all you need.

you need to enable a system assigned identity on the scaleset, which the document shows, as well as a new section for the WAD extension

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostics-extension-schema-windows#example-configuration

This will help you with the sink set up